# How to register multiple folders with one WatchService

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Could somebody guide me how to register multiple folder paths with one watchservice?
Which is better (speed), one WatchService for multiple folders? or one WatchService for one folder path? Multiple folder could be maximum 12!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the Java tutorials (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html):

Here are the basic steps required to implement a watch service:

- Create a WatchService "watcher" for the file system.
- For each directory that you want monitored, register it with the watcher. When registering a directory, you specify the type of events for which you want notification. You receive a WatchKey instance for each directory that you register.
- Implement an infinite loop to wait for incoming events. When an event occurs, the key is signaled and placed into the watcher's queue.
- Retrieve the key from the watcher's queue. You can obtain the file name from the key.
- Retrieve each pending event for the key (there might be multiple events) and process as needed.
- Reset the key, and resume waiting for events.
- Close the service: The watch service exits when either the thread exits or when it is closed (by invoking its closed method).

With 12 folders, I would probably create one thread per WatchKey.

```
  WatchService watcher = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

  // Repeat the following code to get a WatchKey for each folder
  try {
    Path dir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("logs", "access.log");
    WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher,
                           ENTRY_CREATE,
                           ENTRY_DELETE,
                           ENTRY_MODIFY);
  } 
  catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
  }
```

Comment: could you please give me code hint only for the section of registering multiple paths with the watch service? The rest I know. Thanks for your explaination!

Comment: Editet the answer. The useful stuff happens at the line dir.register(watcher, ...);